# I have issue with pgbouncer metrics

Tags: pgbouncer

I have the below pgbouncer metric set in my environment, now am receiving alert for the metric but i have not been resolve the issue.

1. pgbouncer_pools_client_maxwait_seconds :
   we set this metric to above 40 (pgbouncer_pools_client_maxwait_seconds > 40)
2. pgbouncer_pools_client_waiting_connections :
   we set this metric to above 300 (pgbouncer_pools_client_waiting_connections > 300)

This metric alert are triggered, what can i possible check to resolve the issue?

This metric alert are triggered, what can i possible check to resolve the issue?